# Returning the most common guide name in a trip array

Tags: java, arrays, element

I am new to java, and a new student of Computer Science.

I have a question: How can I find the most common name in an array that contains objects
with information about trips?

The array has objects that each of them contains information about trips, and there is the name of guide.
By logic, I understand that I need first to get all guide names, then count each name,
then compare the counters of each name, find the maximum counter, and return the guide that 
contains that maximum counter.. but how do I do this?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do it.  You are on the right track in your approach.  Here's a little more detail about how you could do the things that you mention, in java.

"get all guide names"
This means you have to write a loop over your array, and collect the names in some kind of data structure.  Which data structure to use depends on what you want to do (more on this below).

"count each name"
Aha, so your data structure that collects the names should be able to also store the count for each name.  One of the most versatile data structures in java is the Map.  In this case, you could have a Map to store the count of each name.

"compare the counters", "find the maximum"
You can either do this after you've collected the names into a Map, but it's probably simpler to just do it as you go through the loop.  As you loop over the items in the array, and get the name to update the count, you can also keep track of the "maximum count so far" and the name that goes with it.  Any time you get a name whose new count is greater than this maximum, you would then have a new maximum and corresponding name (at least until you find a bigger one).  Then at the end of the loop you will have the name that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Can you help me with some idea how I connect between the counter and the name? That's where I am stuck.

Comment: The data structure is called a Map in java, sometimes it is called a dictionary or a hash in other languages.  It is a set of key-value pairs.  In your case, you would use the name as the key, and the count as the value.  Each time around the loop, you look in your Map to see if there is a count (the value) associated with the current name (the key).  If not, you insert value 1 as the count, for that name.  If so, you update the Map so that the value is now 1 greater than it was before.